# TwitterRequest Block Syncronization IOS5

Tags: twitter, ios5, objective-c-blocks

I was trying to work on xcode and ios5 and I have a TWRequest to bring down tweets using the Twitter Api.  However, I am confused about how blocks work in iOS5.  For example in this code

```
 [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
    NSArray* firstParse = [dictionary objectForKey:@"results"];

    for (NSDictionary *post in firstParse) {               
        Tweet *tweetMessage = [[Tweet alloc] init];
        tweetMessage.message =  [post objectForKey:@"text"];
        tweetMessage.user =  [post objectForKey:@"from_user"];

        [tweets addObject:tweetMessage];
    }
}];
NSLog(@"%@",[tweets count]);
```

Assuming that I have a tweets = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:25]; call somewhere up top.

However, every time I do this, the count is always at zero.  After doing some testing, I realized that the block code was running after the NSLog was running signifying that the code did not run from top down as I was use to.

Does anyone know how to fix such an issue?

I also tried this later example because I was trying to move the tweets into a viewController that has an array object

```
tweetViewController.tweets = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:25];
[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];
    NSArray* firstParse = [dictionary objectForKey:@"results"];

    for (NSDictionary *post in firstParse)
    {               
        Tweet *tweetMessage = [[Tweet alloc] init];
        tweetMessage.message =  [post objectForKey:@"text"];
        tweetMessage.user =  [post objectForKey:@"from_user"];

        [tweetViewController.tweets addObject:tweetMessage];

        NSLog(@"%d",[tweets count]);
        //NSLog(@"%@: %@", [post objectForKey:@"from_user"], [post objectForKey:@"text"]);            
    }
}];

Tweet *tweetMessage = [[Tweet alloc] init];
tweetMessage.message =  @"HELLO";
tweetMessage.user =  @"HELLO";
[tweetViewController.tweets addObject:tweetMessage];
return YES;
```

The Hello messages display properly but the ones in the block do not.

Comment: Don't do synchronous code if you don't absolutely have to.

Comment: How would I call the request then?

Comment: Just like this, but I meant that you should simply *allow* the code to execute asynchronously. Place the code that's related to the tweet loading inside the block.

Comment: I tried that too now, with this code because I was originally trying to transfer the twitter into a table for a viewController `[tweetViewController.tweets addObject:tweetMessage]; ` and also I tested it outside the block with a ` Tweet *tweetMessage = [[Tweet alloc] init];
    tweetMessage.message =  @"HELLO";
    tweetMessage.user =  @"HELLO";
    [tweetViewController.tweets addObject:tweetMessage];
    return YES; ` 
the hello message displays correctly on the view controller while the ones in the block do not display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't. Basically, focus on making your code asynchronous. This'll be better for the user (the UI will be more smooth) and easier for the developer (yes, really!)

Do everything that's related to loading the tweets in the block instead of after it. Place your `NSLog` in the block instead of outside it. Once you're done loading all the tweets, simply call `[tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];` or something else, to update the UI.

Make sure to avoid using the `nonatomic` flag on the property that stores the `tweets`. You want to avoid invalid cross-thread access.

Comment: Just wondering, where would you call the reload data, im currently doing everything within the app delegate

Comment: You should really use all this code in a View Controller. The App Delegate really shouldn't do any of this - it's responsible for handling the application itself (startup, shutdown, pause, resume, etc).

Comment: How does performSelectorOnMainThread work? Do I call it on the view controller or do I do it while inside the view controller.

Comment: You call it on the UITableView that's supposed to show your tweets, or whatever you are using to show tweets.

Comment: is reloadData just an empty function or is there a significance to it?

Comment: UITableView has a method called `reloadData` which reloads the data, based on information from the Data Source, usually the view controller.

Comment: Don't use perform selector its so passé use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ <UICODE HERE> }); instead